# Вопросы по верстке блока

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь сверстать вот этот блок [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал на flexbox но почемуто мне кажется что это бред:

```css
.con {
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;



}
.imgs {
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 92%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.left_imgs {
    margin-right: 30px;


}



.col2 {


    justify-content: space-between;
    display: flex;

}

.right_imgs {


    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}


.imgs img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
    <section class="sec2">
        <div class="con">
            <div class="imgs">
                <div class="left_imgs ibox">

                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/540x540" alt="">


                </div>
                <div class="right_imgs">
                    <div class="col1 ibox">
      
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/540x255" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="col2">

                        <div class="left_imgs2 ibox">
  
                            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/255x255" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="right_imgs2 ibox">
           
                            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/255x255" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Сам вопрос комплексный:

1. Можно ли сверстать данный блок более легким правильным и кроссбраузерным способом?
2. Почему не масштабируются изображения на IE по классу `.imgs img` в css?
3. И наконец самый волнующий: Как сделать так чтобы на мобильных устройствах срабатывал медиа запрос и 3 изображения справа вставали под картинкой 540x540. Учил гриды и видел там подобное но ,во первых,услышал много советов о том что пока не стоит их юзать из за слабой кроссбраузерности а ,во вторых, интересно было узнать можно ли осуществить данную адаптивность более укоренившимися методами.(PS Слышал что есть в бутстрапе какая то сетка но от него я пока что совсем далек.)

---

Было бы приятно услышать разъяснение по этим вопросам. Заранее спасибо:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы всегда можете сделать это методами "старой школы" [JSfiddle (SCSS)](https://jsfiddle.net/6et2o5ad/21/)

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
}

.parent * {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.parent * .inner {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.parent .rect:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.parent .left {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.parent .right-top {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.parent .right-top:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}

.parent .right-bottom {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: green;
}

.parent .right-bottom + .right-bottom {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left rect">
    <div class="inner">
      First block
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-top">
    <div class="inner">
      Second block
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-bottom rect">
    <div class="inner">
      Third block
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-bottom rect">
    <div class="inner">
      Fourth block
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Приветствуем CSS GRID

```css
    #greed {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas:
        'a a b b'
        'a a c d';
        grid-template-rows: 50vh 50vh;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    }
    #a {
        grid-area: a;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    #b {
        grid-area: b;
        background-color: green;
    }
    #c {
        grid-area: c;
        background-color: black;
    }
    #d {
        grid-area: d;
        background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div id="greed">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
    <div id="c"></div>
    <div id="d"></div>
</div>
```

Ну а вопрос про IE уже стал мемом...

Comment: "Учил гриды и видел там подобное но ,во первых,услышал много советов о том что пока не стоит их юзать из за слабой кроссбраузерности"

Comment: Ну а вообще какого мнения вы на счет юзать иль не юзать

Comment: Номинально CSS Grid имеет [полную поддержку браузерами](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid), но по факту это Candidate Recommendation ([CR](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_W3C#%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_(CR_%E2%80%94_Candidate_Recommendation))), так что использовать его в продакшене не желательно